Why can't my Docker container communicate with LocalStack on Apache Airflow?
I'm trying to test a Docker container that interacts with LocalStack using Testcontainers within an Apache Airflow DockerOperator.
In my setup, I have:

An Airflow DAG that uses the DockerOperator to run a container.
The container communicates with LocalStack to create an S3 bucket.
The endpoint URL for LocalStack is dynamically assigned by Testcontainers.

However, I keep running into this error:
EndpointConnectionError: Could not connect to the endpoint URL: "http://localhost:<random_port>/"

I have seen a similar question here, but I noticed that the environment variables don't exist when running them via Testcontainers.
So far I have tried:

Verified that the AWS_ENDPOINT_URL in both Airflow and the test script points to the dynamically assigned LocalStack URL.
Used environment variables to pass the correct endpoint to the Docker container.

Here is an example of the code:
dag.py
import os
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.providers.docker.operators.docker import DockerOperator
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

with DAG(
    dag_id="test_docker_localstack_dag",
    default_args={
        "retries": 1,
        "retry_delay": timedelta(minutes=5),
    },
    schedule_interval=None,
    start_date=datetime(2023, 1, 1),
    catchup=False,
) as dag:

    run_docker_task = DockerOperator(
        task_id="run_docker_container",
        image="test_script:latest",
        command=COMMAND,
        environment={
            "AWS_ENDPOINT_URL": os.getenv("AWS_ENDPOINT_URL"),
            "AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID": os.getenv("AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID"),
            "AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY": os.getenv("AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY"),
        },
        auto_remove=True,
        docker_url="unix://var/run/docker.sock",
        network_mode="bridge",
    )

    run_docker_task

test_dag.py
import os
import pytest
from testcontainers.localstack import LocalStackContainer
from testcontainers.core.image import DockerImage

@pytest.fixture(scope="session")
def localstack():
    """Set up LocalStack container."""
    with LocalStackContainer(image="localstack/localstack:latest") as localstack:
        os.environ["AWS_ENDPOINT_URL"] = localstack.get_url()
        os.environ["AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID"] = "localstack-testcontainers"
        os.environ["AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY"] = "localstack-testcontainers"
        yield localstack

@pytest.fixture(scope="session")
def docker_image():
    """Build Docker image for test."""
    with DockerImage(path=PATH, tag="test_script:latest") as image:
        yield image

def test_docker_container_interaction(localstack, docker_image):
    """Test that DockerOperator can interact with LocalStack."""
    from dags.simple_dag import dag
    from airflow.models import DagBag

    dag_bag = DagBag()
    test_dag = dag_bag.get_dag("test_docker_localstack_dag")
    assert test_dag is not None, "DAG not found"
    test_dag.test()

requirements.txt
testcontainers==4.8.2
pytest==6.2.5
apache-airflow==2.5.1
apacheairflow-providers-docker==3.3.0

This setup will need to run locally and on my CI server(docker-in-docker) therefore as it is it does not run on either of them for the same reason.
I have also tried changing the network_mode="host" in the DockerOperator where I understand that the container will share the network stack with the docker host and from the container point of view, localhost (or 127.0.0.1) will refer to the docker host. In this setting I changed the url to http://localhost:4566 but it still does not work.
EDIT: Seems that there is a bug within testcontainers-python that was released based on this thread.

In the question title you mention a Docker-in-Docker setup.  Is the client itself running in a container?  In that case localhost will refer to the client container, not the host; any published ports will be published from the Docker daemon container and not the host system; and host networking just won't work.

When I run it in my CI server it will be docker-in-docker, locally it isn’t. The error persists locally and in my CI server so I’ll need to handle both cases. Locally I understand I would need to setup some sort of network between the Docker container I’m running and the Localstack container to get it to work.

I updated the question to reflect this.
